# .htaccess access conditional login based on DOMAIN

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

I haven't been able to find the right answer for this on StackOverflow, so I figured I would ask and hopefully others are looking for the same:

I am using the same .htacess for local, dev and prod and want to `HTTP_AUTH` our DEV box. Here is my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

SetEnvIf Host "localenv" SITE_ENV=LOCAL
SetEnvIf Host "devdomain.com" SITE_ENV=DEV
SetEnvIf Host "proddomain.com" SITE_ENV=PROD

Order deny,allow
Satisfy any
Deny from SITE_ENV=DEV
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

This works when I'm my local enviornment, but when I switch the `Deny from SITE_ENV=DEV` to `Deny from SITE_ENV=LOCAL` I don't get the authentication requirement anymore, which leads me to believe the code isn't working. I also have changed the `AuthUserFile` path to point to the  local `.htpasswd` - but I figured this would show up in the logs if it couldn't find the `.htpasswd` file

Any guidance here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SetEnvIf Host "localenv" SITE_ENV=LOCAL
SetEnvIf Host "devdomain.com" SITE_ENV=DEV
SetEnvIf Host "proddomain.com" SITE_ENV=PROD

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Access"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from SITE_ENV=DEV
Satisfy any
```

Comment: This did not work - any changes I have to make in htaccess file?

Comment: Can you copy/paste your complete .htaccess in the question

Comment: `php_flag display_errors On
php_flag display_startup_errors On

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

SetEnvIf Host "lcoa" SITE_ENV=LOCAL
SetEnvIf Host "devmydomain.com" SITE_ENV=DEV
SetEnvIf Host "prodmydomain.com" SITE_ENV=PROD

AuthType Basic
AuthName "UTDev Access"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
Deny from SITE_ENV=DEV
Satisfy any`

Comment: Are you sure this `SetEnvIf Host "lcoa" SITE_ENV=LOCAL` is right As I don't get what is `lcoa` host?